# ngRepeat acts crazily when adding ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list that pretty much looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="acc in get_acc()">
    {{acc.value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and then it is suppose to print!

something like

```
acc-1
acc-2
acc-3
```

So..I added angular-animate.js to my project and chnaged the angular version to 1.2.4 as well.
added ngAnimate as a dependency to my project!

and use ng-enter etc somewhere else!

and this thing goes crazy!

all of a sudden  the list looks like this!

```
acc-1
acc-2
acc-3
acc-2
acc-1
acc-3
........
```

all possible permutations!

And in the console I have.

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.4/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3A…%20newVal%3A%20%5C%22acc-1%5C%22%3B%20oldVal%3A%20undefined%22%5D%5D
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:6:449
    at h.$digest (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:100:188)
    at h.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at h.$apply (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:102:100)
    at h.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:17:415
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:30:352)
    at Xb.c (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:17:323)
    at Xb (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.min.js:18:30) angular.min.js:84
(anonymous function)
```

Any idea what is happening?
Angular docs already are terrible at basics and now this things have no explanation!

Comment: IF you could reproduce this behavior in plunkr or jsfiddle  it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Angular, you can find a detailed explanation and discussion at this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3613).

Comment: Shall I go back to a prev version, where I wont need ngAnimate as a separate dependency ?

I needed snimations for ng-show.. now its messing up my ng-repeat!